# how to change value of ace in blackjack if card value goes over 21

Tags: java, blackjack

This is one of my classes for my blackjack program in java. I got the whole thing running except for a problem with the Ace. The problem occurs when the user's card value is over 21 and it checks if there is an Ace. This is where this code comes into play. But when the user stands, the dealer keeps hitting until it has a higher value than the user. Problem is, if dealer goes over 21, it's value gets subtracted too by 10, even though the dealer doesn't have an ace. It's because the variable d contains 52 ints (0-51), and if there is an ace in the user's cards, it reads it again for the dealer's cards. Is there a way, so that it only does it when there IS an ace? Thanks in advance

```
int d=0; int s=0; int m=1;
cardValue=user's Card value
dealerValue=dealer's card value

public void aceDeck(){
    //check to see if user/dealer has an Ace, and whether or not it should be come a 1 or an 11, depending on
    //the user's or dealer's value
    for (d=s; d<deck.length; d++){
        if(deck[d].contains("Ace")) {
            System.err.println(d);
            while(m==1){
                dealerUser-=10;
                m++;
            }
        }
    }
    m=0;
    s=d; 
    if (BlackJack.userOrDealer.equals("user")){
        cardValue=dealerUser;
    } else {
        dealerValue=dealerUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: tell me if you need the whole code to explain the answer- thanks

Comment: Is this a school project? Not that we can't help you if it is but you should point out if it is so we can give a better explanation versus just telling you what's wrong.

Comment: @Sirens yes its a school project

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class BlackJack {
public static int money=100;
public static String userOrDealer;
public static String hide="show";
public static int bet;
static Scanner dollars =new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hitStand;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("------WELCOME TO BLACKJACK------\n");
    delay(7);
    do{
        System.out.println("You can bet up to $"+money+".");

        System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
        bet=dollars.nextInt();
        do{if (bet<0||bet>money){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid amount.");
            bet=dollars.nextInt();
        }
            }while(bet<0||bet>money);


        Deck deck= new Deck();//call on the class Deck
        deck.makeDeck();//call on public void makeDeck
        deck.shuffleDeck();//call on public void suffleDeck

        userOrDealer="user";//so dealerUser can add values to user's hand
        //Output
        System.out.println("Your Hand\n");
        delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
        //Output
        System.out.println("Drawing Cards...\n");
        delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
        deck.checkDeck();//call on public void checkDeck
        delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
        deck.checkDeck();//call on public void checkDeck
        delay(5);//delay next output by 0.5 sec
        deck.printDeck();//call on public void printDeck
        System.out.println("");

        if (Deck.cardValue==21){
            //Output
            System.out.println("BLACKJACK");//if user automatically gets the value of 21, the user wins
            System.out.println("You Win!");
        }else{
            //Output
            System.out.println("Dealer hand\n");
            delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
            userOrDealer="dealer";//so dealerUser can add values to dealer's hand
            System.out.println("Drawing Cards...\n");
            delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
            deck.checkDeck();//call on public void checkDeck
            hide="hide";//to hide the 2nd card of the dealer's deck so the user can't see it
            delay(1);//delay next output by 1 sec
            deck.checkDeck();//call on public void checkDeck
            delay(5);//delay next output by 0.5 sec
            deck.printDeck();//call on public void printDeck
            hide="show";//reset variable so that the next cards will be shown to the user

            do{//do loop to prevent unexpected inputs
                //Output
                System.out.println("\nHIT or STAND");
                //Input
                hitStand=scan.next();
            }while(!hitStand.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")&&!hitStand.equalsIgnoreCase("stand"));

            while(hitStand.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")){
        System.out.println("Your Hand\n");
        delay(1000);
        userOrDealer="user";
         System.out.println("Drawing a Card...\n");
         delay(1000);
        deck.checkDeck();
         if (Deck.dealerUser>21){
        deck.aceDeck();
         }
        delay(500);
        deck.printDeck();
        if (Deck.dealerUser>=21)break;
        do{
        System.out.println("HIT or STAND");
        hitStand=scan.next();
    }while(!hitStand.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")&&!hitStand.equalsIgnoreCase("stand"));

            }

  Winner win=new Winner(); 
  win.checkWinner();

  if (Deck.cardValue<21){
    delay(500);
    System.out.println("Dealer Hand\n");
    System.out.println(Deck.deck[2]);
    System.out.println(Deck.deck[3]);
    delay(500);
    System.out.println("\nThe Dealer's hand is currently valued at: "+Deck.dealerValue+"\n");

  while(Deck.dealerValue<=16||Deck.dealerUser<Deck.cardValue){
      delay(1000);
      System.out.println("Drawing a Card...\n");
      delay(1000);
      userOrDealer="dealer";
        deck.checkDeck();
         if (Deck.dealerUser>21){
        deck.aceDeck();
         }
        delay(500);
        deck.printDeck();

            }


   win.winner();
   }
}
System.out.println("");
deck.cardValue=0;
deck.dealerValue=0;
deck.dealerUser=0;
deck.y=0;
    }while(money>0);
    System.out.println("You lost all your money.");
    System.out.println("Game Over!");
}
public static void delay(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
    }
}
}
```

deck:

```
public class Deck extends BlackJack{
public static int cardValue=0;//card value of user
public static int dealerValue=0;//card value of dealer
public static int dealerUser;//neutral value of card that switches between the dealer's and user's card value
String userDealer;//neutral variable that either out puts the user's hand or dealer's hand
int hideDealer;//to hide the 2nd card of the dealer form the user
int m=1;
public static int x=-1;
public static int y=0;
int g;
int s=0;
static String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};//the card Suits
static String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};//the card ranks
static int n = suits.length * ranks.length; //number of cards in a deck (52)
public static String[] deck = new String[n];//variable that will hold all the 52 cards of the deck
int d;
int v=0;

 public void makeDeck() {
 //make the 52 card deck
     for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
              deck[suits.length*i + j] = ranks[i] + " of " + suits[j];            
          }//End of for j < suits.length
      }//End of for i < ranks.length
  }//End of public void makeDeck


 public void shuffleDeck(){
 //shuffle the 52 card deck
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
         String temp = deck[r];
         deck[r] = deck[i];
         deck[i] = temp;
     }//End of for i < n
 }//End of public void shuffleDeck


 public void checkDeck(){
 //output the suite and the rank of a card, and add the value to the user's or dealer's total value
    x++;
    y++;
    if(BlackJack.userOrDealer.equals("user")){
    //to switch between the user's value and the dealer's value
        //Calculation
        dealerUser=cardValue;//the neutral variable is equal to the user's value

    }//End of if userOrDealer=user 
    else{
        //Calculation
        dealerUser=dealerValue;//the neutral variable is equal to the dealer's value
    }//End of else

    for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {


        if (BlackJack.hide.equals("hide")){//used for hiding the 2nd card of the dealer's hand
            //Output
            System.out.println("[HIDDEN]"); 
        }//End of if hide=hide
        else {
        System.out.println(deck[i]);//output the card rank and suit
        }//End of else
        if(deck[i].contains("Ace")) {
            if (dealerUser<=10){ //if the user's or dealer's value is lower than 10,
                //Calculation    //the Ace has the value of of 11 
                dealerUser+=11;
            }//End of if dealerUser <=10
            else {               //else if the user's or dealer's value is greater than 10, 
                dealerUser+=1;   //the Ace has a value of 1 (so user/dealer doesn't go over 21)
            }//End of else
        }//End of if deck[i] contains an Ace
        else if(deck[i].contains("King")||deck[i].contains("Queen")||deck[i].contains("Jack")||deck[i].contains("10")) {
            //Calculation
            dealerUser+=10; //if the user/dealer gets a 10 or a face card, the user/dealer value is increased by 10 
        }//end of else if deck[i] contains a face card or a 10
        else{
        dealerUser+=Character.getNumericValue(deck[i].charAt(0)); //the value of the string (1, 2, 3 etc) is added to 
    }//End of else                                                //the current value of the user's or dealer's hand
        }//end of for i < y

    if (BlackJack.userOrDealer.equals("user")){
        //Calculation
        cardValue=dealerUser;//the user's value is updated from the neutral value

    }//End of if userOrDealer = user
    else {
        //Calculation
        dealerValue=dealerUser;//the dealer's value is updated from the neutral value
    }//End of else
}//End of public void checkDeck


 public void aceDeck(){
     //check to see if user/dealer has an Ace, and whether or not it should be come a 1 or an 11, depending on
     //the user's or dealer's value




             for (d=s; d<deck.length; d++){

                 if(deck[d].contains("Ace")) {
                     System.err.println(d);
                     while(m==1){

                         dealerUser-=10;
                         m++;
                    }
                 }
            }
             m=0;
             s=d; 






             if(BlackJack.userOrDealer.equals("user")){
                    //to switch between the user's value and the dealer's value
                        //Calculation
                        cardValue=dealerUser;//the neutral variable is equal to the user's value

                    }//End of if userOrDealer=user 
                    else{
                        //Calculation
                        dealerValue=dealerUser;//the neutral variable is equal to the dealer's value
                    }//End of else
```

}

```
public void printDeck(){
    //output the value of the user's or dealer's hand

    if(BlackJack.userOrDealer.equals("user")){
        userDealer="Your hand";

    }//End of if userOrDealer = user
    else{
        userDealer= "The dealer's hand";
    }//End of else

    if (BlackJack.hide.equals("hide")){ //store the value of the dealer's hidden card but not print it out so the user can see
        if (deck[3].contains("Jack")||deck[3].contains("Queen")||deck[3].contains("King")||deck[3].contains("10")){
            //Calculation
            hideDealer=10;//gets the value of the hidden card
        }//End of if deck[3] contains a face card or a 10
        else if(deck[3].contains("Ace")) {
            //Calculation
            hideDealer=11;//gets the value of hidden card 
        }//End of if deck[3] contains Ace
        else{
            //Calculation
            hideDealer=Character.getNumericValue(deck[3].charAt(0));//gets value of the hidden card 
        }//End of else
        //Calculation
        hideDealer=dealerUser-hideDealer;//subtracts the hidden value so user cannot guess what the card is
        //Output
        System.out.println("\n"+userDealer+" is currently valued at: "+hideDealer);

    }//End of if Hide equals hide
    else{

        //Output
        System.out.println("\n"+userDealer+" is currently valued at: "+dealerUser);
    }//End of else 
}//End of public void printDeck

}//End of class
```

winner:

```
public class Winner extends BlackJack {


public void winner(){
    if(Deck.dealerValue>21){//If dealer goes over 21
        //Output
        System.out.println("\nDealer BUSTS");
        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){//If user bet, user reclaims user's original bet + the same amount from the "dealer"
            //Calculation
            BlackJack.money+=BlackJack.bet;
            //Output
            System.out.println("\nYou won $"+BlackJack.bet+"!");
        }//End of if bet !=0
        else {
            //Output
            System.out.println("You Win!");
        }//End of else
    }//End of if dealerValue>21
    else if(Deck.dealerValue==21){
        //Output
        System.out.println("\nDealer gets BLACKJACK");
        System.out.println("The Dealer Wins!");
        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){//If user bet, user loses the money user bets  
            //Calculation
            BlackJack.money-=BlackJack.bet;
            //Output
            System.out.println("\nYou lost $"+BlackJack.bet+".");
        }//End of if bet!=0;
    }//End of if dealerValue==21
    else if (Deck.dealerValue<Deck.cardValue){
        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){//If user bet, user reclaims user's original bet + the same amount from the "dealer" 
            //Calculation
            BlackJack.money+=BlackJack.bet;
            //Output
            System.out.println("\nYou won $"+BlackJack.bet+"!");
        }//End of if bet!=0
        else{
            //Output
            System.out.println("\nYou Win!");
        }//End of else
    }//End of if dealerValue<cardValue
    else {
        //Output
        System.out.println("\nDealer Wins!");
        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){//If user bet, user loses the money user bets   
            //Calculation
            BlackJack.money-=BlackJack.bet;
            //Output
            System.out.println("\nYou lost $"+BlackJack.bet+".");
        }//End of if bet!=0
    }//End of else


}//End of public void winner


public void checkWinner(){
    if (Deck.cardValue>21){
        System.out.println("\nBUST");
        System.out.println("The Dealer Wins!");
        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){
            BlackJack.money-=BlackJack.bet;
            System.out.println("\nYou lost $"+BlackJack.bet+".");
            }
    }
    else if (Deck.cardValue==21){
        System.out.println("\nBLACKJACK");

        if (BlackJack.bet!=0){
            BlackJack.money+=BlackJack.bet;
            System.out.println("\nYou won $"+BlackJack.bet+"!");
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("You Win!");
        }
    }
    else{

    }
}
}
```

Comment: the delays aren't finished yet.. i just put them there to remind myself later where to put them